# Matplotlib candlestick_ochl and pandas dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot candlestick in matplotlib. But it just shows an empty graph(see pic). I'm not getting any errors in my console. And wondering what may be wrong?

```
print(df.head(5))

             Open   High    Low  Close    Volume
Date                                            
2013-11-19  274.9  275.0  268.5  270.3  671065.0
2013-11-20  270.0  273.0  267.5  269.5  381580.0
2013-11-21  268.0  273.0  265.5  271.5  313084.0
2013-11-22  272.5  272.5  266.2  267.5  486462.0
2013-11-25  269.5  274.7  269.5  273.7  412056.0

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ochl

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((4,4), (0,0), rowspan=3, colspan=4)

candlestick_ochl(ax1, 
                [date2num(df.index.tolist()), df['Open'], df['Close'], df['High'], df['Low']], 
                width=1, 
                colorup='g', 
                colordown='r')

plt.show()
```

[image]